# Extraction of values from SAS Macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have defined macro variable

```
%let data_names = fuzzy_Data_segment EMWS2.Clus_TRAIN;
```

Then I have written a macro to extract and print the values from the above macro variable as:

```
 %macro calling_data;
   %do i = 1 %to 2;
     %let data_name&i = %qscan(&data_names,&i);
     %put &&data_name&i;
   %end;
 %mend;
 %calling_data;
```

My macro code is able print the first name(fuzzy_Data_segment), but, it is only printing the part of the second name(EMWS2). what should I do to print the entire second name

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that SAS considers a period to be one of the default delimiters in macro variables. In this case, it looks like you want to be using a space to delimit items in data_names, so specify that:

```
%let data_name&i= %qscan(&data_names,&i., %str( ));
```

You're also missing semicolons in your `%let` statement and in your call to `calling_data`.

Comment: You may add that a dot is along the default delimiters (**blank ! $ % & ( ) * + , - . / ; < ^¦**) and thats why the macro was not working as intended.

Comment: You don't want to use physical quotes in macro language as argument to %QSCAN.  You want to use quoting function %STR( )